# Comparison on two columns from two text files using numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have two files with the txt format as shown below:

File 1: Delimiter ^

```
ID^Name^Address^Date of Join^Pin^Country
1^John^No 123. Ml^2016-06-30^123123^USA
2^Shaw^No 13. MX^2014-02-30^423123^UK
3^Donn^No 453. MR^2015-01-30^523123^UAE
```

File 2: Delimiter |

```
Name|ID|Address|Date of Join|Pin|Country
John|1|No 123. Ml|2016-06-30|123123|USA
Shaw|2|No 13. MX|2014-02-30|423123|UK
Donn|3|No 453. MR|2015-01-02|523123|UAE
Donn|4|No 1. XR|2012-03-10|523123|UAE
```

I want to do comparison on two 2 columns namely `ID` and `Date of Join`.

**My try**: I am using numpy for this.

```
import numpy as np
data1 = np.loadtxt('E:\File1.txt', delimiter='^')
data2 = np.loadtxt('E:\File2.txt', delimiter='|')
np.savetxt('E:\Output.txt',data2[data1[:,0]!=data2[:,1] or data1[:,3]!=data2[:,3],:])
```

But getting an error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`np.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) with `dtype=None` for automatic data type detection:

```
data1 = np.loadtxt('E:\File1.txt', dtype=None, delimiter='^')
```

Comment: After changing to `np.genfromtxt` got new error `ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`.

Comment: That's probably because the dimensions of the two files do not line up, and your code assumes they do.  Try to fix it.